# Why does the "Mouse" preferences GUI not allow me to enable two-finger scrolling?

Tags: drivers, multi-touch, touchpad, synaptics

I know that my touchpad is capable of it. I can enable glitch-free two-finger scrolling by running this script:

```
#! /bin/sh

synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=1
synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=1
synclient EmulateTwoFingerMinW=10
synclient EmulateTwoFingerMinZ=48
```

However, in the "Mouse" preferences GUI, the "two-finger scrolling" option is greyed out. It worked fine on my old laptop.

[Here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/499772/lshw) is the output of `sudo lshw -sanitize`, if it makes a difference.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? And what laptop is this?

Comment: It's Ubuntu 10.10 on a Dell Studio XPS 16 (but I've had this problem since at least 10.04). You can see the details of my hardware in the `lshw` output that I posted.

Comment: Please use the `synaptics` tag instead of `synaptic` to put your question in the list of Synaptics (touchpad) questions, rather than with the Synaptic Package Manager questions. (Oh how I long to have 200 rep so I can just do this housekeeping myself.)

Comment: @Voyagerfan5761: Done. Good call, I was wondering why there were so many questions about touchpads.

Comment: There are enough touchpad questions. I asked one myself. They can be finicky little buggers. Glad you found my suggestion useful. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my understanding of it. Ubuntu doesn't have support for the Synaptics touchpad <strike>officially</strike> out of the box, so what that script does is it *emulates* the multi-touch. I think. I don't know for sure, but that is my understanding of that. (I myself have a Synapatics trackpad on my Asus Eee PC, so I've spent a far amount of time working on this.)

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, write `gconf-editor`, it will open `gconf-editor`, go to destkop, gnome, peripherals, touchpad and type 2 for the variable "scroll_method". The option will stay grayed but two finger scroll will be enable. Works for me.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work for me. It's ok though--I've got two-finger scrolling working, I just want to know *why* I couldn't do it from the GUI.

Comment: There's no variable named "scroll_method".

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a laptop to test it with, but I recently stumbled upon this site: http://stuffivelearned.org/doku.php?id=os:linux:general:synapticstouchtricks

Perhaps this helps you.